# Copy a string(same value) and turn it into an array

Tags: java, arrays

Is there any way to copy a string like this and put it into an array?

String s = "Hello"; -> String[] s = {"Hello", "Hello"};

The array must copy what's inside of s.

Comment: @burrito77 yes, twice or even thrice. depends on the for loop

Comment: In my answer I ask for user input, but you can manipulate my answer however you'd like. If you don't know how you'd manipulate mine, then I can fix it for you if you be more specific on your larger goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so with:

```
String[] resultSet = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
                              .mapToObj(i -> s)
                              .toArray(String[]::new);
```

or:

```
String[] resultSet = Stream.generate(() -> s)
                           .limit(n)
                           .toArray(String[]::new);
```

where `n` is the number of times you want to generate the string `s`.

Example:

```
int n = 2;
String s = "Hello";
String[] resultSet = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
                              .mapToObj(i -> s)
                              .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultSet));
```

would print:

```
[Hello, Hello]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method like

```
public String[] copyString(String s, int nr) {
    String[] arr = new String[nr];
    for(int i=0; i<nr; i++) {
        arr[i] = s;
    }
    return arr;
}
```